# Get the last 6 rows of MySQL and define the variables for each?

Tags: php, mysql, database, graph

So, I am going to be running this script every 4 hours to populate my database.

My question is is it possible to get the last 6 rows and define the variables for each?

So I can use them to create a last 24 hour graph..

like:

$value1,$time1,$ap1

$value2,$time2,$ap2

$value3,$time3,$ap3

$value4,$time4,$ap4

$value5,$time5,$ap5

$value6,$time6,$ap6

```
<?php
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($c, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.bungie.net/stats/reach/online.aspx',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    ));
$r = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

preg_match_all('|([\w\s]+)</a> </h4>\s*([0-9,]+) Players|s', $r, $m);
$teams = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
foreach ($m[2] as &$v) $v = str_replace(',','',$v);
//echo '<pre>'.print_r($teams,1).'</pre>';

//array with values
$a = $m[2];
//define idividual variables
$noble_map_pack = $a[0];
$rumble_pit = $a[1];
$living_dead = $a[2];
$team_slayer = $a[3];
$mlg = $a[4];
$team_swat = $a[5];
$team_snipers = $a[6];
$team_objective = $a[7];
$multi_team = $a[8];
$big_team_battle = $a[9];
$invasion = $a[10];
$firefight = $a[11];
$score_attack = $a[12];
$coop_campaign = $a[13];
$team_arena = $a[14];
$doubles_arena = $a[15];
$ffa_arena = $a[16];

//define time variables
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$time = date("g:i");
$ap = date("A");
$date = date("YmdHis");

//include_once "mysql_con.php";
$d_host = "localhost";
$d_user = "";
$d_pass = "";
$d_name = "database";

@mysql_connect("$d_host","$d_user","$d_pass") or die ("Could not connect!");
@mysql_select_db("$d_name") or die ("No database!");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `noblemappack`
(`value`,`time`,`ap`,`date`)
VALUES ('".$noble_map_pack."','".$time."','".$ap."','".$date."')")

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query (assuming `time` is a `datetime` column that can be sorted):

```
SELECT * FROM `noblemappack` ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 6
```

If you don't have a datetime field you can sort by, add one. "The last 6" is pretty vague otherwise.
If you just put the result in an array, you're all set. You shouldn't keep values in individual variables, keeping them as sets of data in an array is much easier to work with.

```
array(
    array('value' => 'foo', 'time' => '13:45', 'date' => '2011-02-03'),
    array('value' => 'bar', 'time' => '22:41', 'date' => '2011-02-04'),
    ...
);
```

Same for your other variables:

```
list($data['noble_map_pack'], $data['rumble_pit'], ...) = $a;
```